# Slash in branch name in Gemfile causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I have this in my Gemfile (using a branch with a slash):

```
gem 'ice_cube', github: 'seejohnrun/ice_cube', branch: 'issues/50-from_ical'
```

Which produces this error:

```
$ bundle
Updating git://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube.git
fatal: ambiguous argument 'issues/50-from_ical': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Git error: command `git rev-parse issues/50-from_ical` in directory
/Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@example/cache/bundler/git/ice_cube-63812451ddbe2391df352dbcaee4a6cf04a9f746 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'/Users/jp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@example/cache/bundler/git/ice_cube-63812451ddbe2391df352dbcaee4a6cf04a9f746'
```

Other branches (without slashes) work. Does anyone know how to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: try escaping the the / as \/ ?  not sure if that will do anything as never tried..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the issue is the `/`? I checked the [referenced repo](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) and there is no public branch `issues/50-from_ical`.

I believe the problem is that the branch doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Doh! Well that was embarrassing. Thanks for pointing it out. The branch is in a fork here https://github.com/greenriver/ice_cube/tree/issues/50-from_ical. I'm blaming late night coding for that one.